# Added website with a subdomain on Mountain Lion server couldn't be found on other machines

Tags: macos, network, dns, server.app

My server is accessible via example.com and I want my website to be accessed via sub.example.com. I added a website to Mountain Lion server with domain name that's actually a subdomain; sub.example.com. I than added a new host name to DNS service, so that the hostname sub.example.com resolves to the IP address of the server (192.168.1.2).

Now, I can view the website sub.example.com on the server itself, but other clients in the local network are not able to access the website.

The command *nslookup sub.example.com* has this result:

```
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Name:       sub.example.com
Address:    192.168.1.2
```

Did I configure the website correctly? What's going wrong?